# how to use jquery from cdn in react's component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Jquery with CDN in react's `index.html` file.. Unfortunatelly, this is how it should be and can't install `react` separately with `yarn`.

How can I use now `$` in React's components ?

I can't do `import $ from Jquery`. and if i use `$` directly, it's not defined.

Any idea ?

I also tried `useEffect`, but in that, `$` is not defined at first.

Comment: you should not use jquery in react as it is bad practice as per react docs because it voilates react ui tree principles. You need to use useRef() hook for playing with nodes directly.
If still you want to use jquery then you can with npm i $.

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you fixed this?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with npm or yarn.

```
npm install jquery

import $ from "jquery"
```

I have tried it and its working fine.

```
 if ($(".enclosing_container ").length) {
      $(".enclosing_container div").remove();
    } else {
      $(".main-row div").remove();
      this.setState({ focusUI: false });
    }
```

Comment: I mentioned that I can't install Jquery like that and only can use it with `cdn`

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a bad practice to use jquery with JS frameworks, But here is a way to use `jquery` with React.js using `CDN`

You can add jquery CDN in index.html and then use the jquery global `$` using window object, and this worked for me.

Here is my App.js file (For demo purpose, you may use in different components) :

```
export default function App() {
  const changeText = () => {
    console.log(window.$("#hetal"));
    window.$("h1").append(' your text here');
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 id="hetal">Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={() => changeText()}>Change</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: code with output snapshot here]

**window object** :
Every external js file added to `React.js` is stored in the window object. So the functions of that js file can be accessed with `window` object in `React.js components`.

You can check the demo on this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-meadow-2vwn27?file=/src/App.js)